# Logging to website, make authorization via Headers parameter with httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, jsp, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, putty

I'm trying to log in to website. Following settings works when i use putty:

```
GET /WindchillCProdA/netmarkets/jsp/netmarkets/view.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.host_address.com
Cookie: action_number=0
Authorization: Basic bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

I've used following code to make the same thing in C#:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.webpage.com/WindchillCProdA/netmarkets/jsp/netmarkets/view.jsp");
        request.Method = "GET";
        CookieContainer gaCookies = new CookieContainer();
        gaCookies.Add(new Cookie("action_number", "0") { Domain = request.Host });
        request.Host = www.host_address.com;
        request.CookieContainer = gaCookies;
        request.UserAgent = "HTTP/1.1";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=";
```

I'm receiving:
*The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.*

I suspect that i have to fill somehow view.jsp because my parameters are not used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use post method and write on request stream the values,
i Checked the web site and i was redirected to another page the code should be as bellow

```
//there could be some hash check the scripts via inspect Element
string postData = String.Format("email={0}&newPassword={1}", "yourusername","yourPassword");
var request =    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://secure.systemsecure.com/host/login/23.htm");
getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
getRequest.UserAgent ="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
newStream.Close();
var getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
```